# Retrieve apprequest giving the user_id

Tags: facebook, apprequests

Is it possible to retrieve the app_ids which have sent requests to me? I try to do so through FQL

```
 Select app_id from apprequest where recipient_uid=me();
```

But I got a result as

```
  {
  "error": {
  "message": "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable 
    column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from  
     http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ", 
  "type": "NoIndexFunctionException", 
   "code": 604
 }
 }
```

What's wrong with my logic? Is there anyway for me to get the list of the apps which send me the request through FQL?

Answer (score 0):

> What's wrong with my logic?

Nothing. The docs page the error message itself links to says that `recipient_uid` *is* an indexable field. Typical litte FB-f*ckup I guess. You should see if there’s a bug report for this already, and if not create one.

The Graph API `user` object has an `apprequests` connection, have you tried that one?

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dapprequests.fields(to%2Capplication%2Ccreated_time%2Cdata%2Cfrom%2Cid%2Cmessage)

Comment: Thank you very much. I rewrite my code as $response= $facebook->api('me/apprequests'); But the problem I face now is that the result I got is always empty. I asked some friend to send me app requests but I still got empty result. Why I can not get correct result.